# Can code-first based data layer be forward compatible with the DB model that uses migrations?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We are using Entity Framework Code First for our application. Migrations has also been enabled, and we upgrade our database through the migration scripts generated by using migrate.exe.

On a production environment, we would like to upgrade the database in-place (without downtime). In order to do this, we want to first upgrade the database, while the front-end nodes are still running an older copy of the application. Once the DB is upgraded, we would then upgrade individual application nodes one at a time.

Is this possible with Code-first and Migrations? Currently, when we try to have the older version of the application connect to a newer "migrated" version of the database, it throws the context out of sync exception (which is expected).

Answer (score 0):

You could set your database initialization strategy to null to prevent your context from checking to see if there are any discrepancies

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
```